# How do I do a JQuery, Ajex call to a Spring Web Flow Event?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

How can I do a JQuery Ajax call to a Spring Web Flow Event changing the eventId to 'loadSchools'?

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#borough").change(function() {
            alert("Changed");


       });
    });
</script>
```

its not a lot of code its just waiting for a dropdown to be changed and then I need to kick off an event to the spring webflow with the eventid of 'loadSchools'

Comment: I'd start by writing `$.ajax(` or one of the helper methods, such as `$.get` or `$.post`

Comment: I don't know agax etc.. can you maybe post a example

Answer (score 0):

I use the following JSP-based JQuery to POST to webflow and redirect (although the redirect is not required):

```
function getPagePostDataStr() {
        return "testitem=test&testitem2=test2";
}

function postDataToWebFlow(reDirectEvent, postDataStr) {            
        //create the POSTDATA param string which includes the eventId
        params = "_eventId="+reDirectEvent+"&"+postDataStr;

        //POST the data
        $.post('${flowExecutionUrl}', params, function(){
            window.location.href = "${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId="+reDirectEvent;
        });
}
```

Then I can use as follows:

```
postDataToWebFlow("myEventId", getPagePostDataStr());
```

I believe you may still need the hidden field on the JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
```